# How to modify an advanced filter copy

Tags: excel, vba, vb6

I have a list similar to this:

```
EO
EV
EA
EZ
Extra Bar(s) Loaded
Extra Pc(s) in Cut Pattern
Extra Pc(s) in Make Up Bar
BB Substitution
EL
Set Up Bar(s)
Missed Lab
```

I am using

```
wrksh.Range("F4:F" & rn).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=ActiveSheet.Range("L4"), Unique:=True
```

to copy unique item to range "L4" from the column "F".

I want to sort them with the ones greater in length than 2 first, then the 2 letter items below them, all in column "L4" and down.

Can that be accomplished with the advanced filter copy to function? If not how would I modify a normal sort routine to list all the "long" ones first, then the "short" ones?

I'm using VB6 to build the excel sheet.

The final result should look like this:

```
BB Substitution
Extra Bar(s) Loaded
Extra Pc(s) in Cut Pattern
Extra Pc(s) in Make Up Bar
Missed Lab
Set Up Bar(s)
EA
EL
EO
EV
EZ
```

Comment: I think the best solution would be to "insert" a new column where you use `=Len(L4)` and then `AutoFill`. Then you sort the 2 columns, L+the new one with the formula, on numbers largest to smallest.  Afterwards you loop through column L to find the first cell containing 2 values, e.g. EA and -1 that range with 1, so you find the range containing text with more than 2 chars. Afterwards, you solve that range on A to Z. Then you will achieve the above.

Comment: Yeah, that's where I've been leaning, but was hoping someone might know a way that was a little neater/cleaner. Thanks.